# Function argument to push and minus

Tags: php, function, math, arguments

Try to use function argument in PHP to plus and minus int.

**My functions is :**

```
function int_test($arg) {
    $main = date('m');
    return intval($main.$arg);
}
```

**so when i test :**

```
echo int_test(); // 11
echo int_test(-1); // 11
echo int_test(1); // 11
```

Whats happen ? or how can I do ?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why are you not passing the parameter as an integer in the first place?

Comment: Just test and simple function guys...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function int_test($arg = 0) {
    $main = date('m');
    return intval($arg) + $main;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.` will concatenate the numeric string returned from date (`$main`) with the argument (`$arg`) you pass into your `int_test` function, so you end up with the strings "11-1" or "11+1" in your

```
return intval($main.$arg);
```

The return value will will be the valid numeric data from the string "11+1" up to the first invalid character (here "+" or "-") which leaves you with 11.

From the PHP Manual:

> [*String conversion to numbers*](http://docs.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)
>
> When a string is evaluated in a numeric context, the resulting value and type are determined as follows. The string will be evaluated as a float if it contains any of the characters '.', 'e', or 'E'. Otherwise, it will be evaluated as an integer. The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero). Valid numeric data is an optional sign, followed by one or more digits (optionally containing a decimal point), followed by an optional exponent. The exponent is an 'e' or 'E' followed by one or more digits.